# Python, open.system function - error with having spaces in the file name

Tags: python

I am trying to open a file from my system folder.

```
import os

Folder = "C:\\Users\\kasan\\Videos"
File = Folder+'\\'+os.listdir(Folder)[0]

print(File) #C:\Users\kasan\Videos\big bang theoryE12S6.mp4
os.startfile(Folder)#open the folder
os.system(File) #should open the mp4 file
```

But os.system() is throwing me an error. Below is the error.

```
'C:\Users\kasan\Videos\big' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

instead of reading 'big bang theoryE12S6.mp4' it is reading only the first part.
How to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Why are you using `os.system`?

Comment: As I mentioned in my script comment.. to open a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the file name in double quotes to preserve whitespaces:

```
os.system('"%s"' % File)
```

Comment: Ah!! Good old string formatting... How did I forgot about this.. Anyways Thanks!!